# Newbie question - CD cmd not working - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: command-line

[Screeshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8dNA.png)

I am in my home folder, I can list the folders their and can see 'Documents' folder. But when I issue CD command - it says no such folder or directory!

Comment: Please copy and paste those texts

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is Case Sensitive.

cd **D**ocuments would work.

cd documents failed because there is no directory **d**ocuments.

Answer (score 1):

There is one error in your command and a gotcha.

Linux is a case sensitive OS `cd documents` referees to different directory than `cd Documents`.

By omitting the full path `/home/mordred/Documents` this path is evaluated as a relative path, if the command is issued from a different working directory it would fail.

Comment: :) Case sensitive ://)

Comment: Thank you soo much!